# How to override objective-c project with a whole new Swift project(start over)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to migrate my old app from objective-c to swift by re-starting the swift project from the scratch.

I wish to use the same package name and app icon.

All the migration tutorials tell me to do bridging work between objective-c and swift. But I just want to restart using swift. Start anew.

Is there a way to do this?

Would simply erasing all storyboards, .h and .m files(and create anew using swift) work?

To be more specific, I was stuck at replacing AppDelegate.h, .m with AppDelegate.swift, which uses Core Data.

Comment: I'd create a new project from scratch (that's what I do) and fill needed stuff by and by.

Comment: I migrated a lot of projects from ObjC to Swift. I added Swift files one by one with the same name as the ObjC files in order first `view` then `model` then `controller` classes, then tested them by checking/unchecking the target membership and deleted the ObjC files it the test succeeded. The benefit is to keep the project with all build and interface settings.

Comment: @ThomasKilian what about using the same package name? would that be possible?

Comment: I rename the exiting project to project-old or the like and create the new with the correct name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you literally want to start again from scratch then do just that. Make a brand new project but use the same bundle identifier, that way when you send it to the app store it will update the original app. I did this recently with an old app of ours on the store and it worked perfectly.

Comment: We did the same but created problem for core data migration, don't know how to do it.